# Can't access 'plans' section when creating service broker in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

Documentation for Service Broker API:

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/services/api.html#authentication

The documentation above claims to implement /v2/catalog to return a json similar to the following:

```
{
"services": [{
"name": "fake-service",
"id": "acb56d7c-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-feb140a59a66",
"description": "fake service",
"tags": ["no-sql", "relational"],
"requires": ["route_forwarding"],
"bindable": true,
"metadata": {
  "provider": {
    "name": "The name"
  },
  "listing": {
    "imageUrl": "http://example.com/cat.gif",
    "blurb": "Add a blurb here",
    "longDescription": "A long time ago, in a galaxy far far away..."
  },
  "displayName": "The Fake Broker"
},
"dashboard_client": {
  "id": "398e2f8e-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-19a71ecbcf64",
  "secret": "277cabb0-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7822c0a90e5d",
  "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:1234"
},
"plan_updateable": true,
"plans": [{
  "name": "fake-plan-1",
  "id": "d3031751-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-a42377d3320e",
  "description": "Shared fake Server, 5tb persistent disk, 40 max concurrent connections",
  "max_storage_tb": 5,
  "metadata": {
    "costs":[
        {
           "amount":{
              "usd":99.0
           },
           "unit":"MONTHLY"
        },
        {
           "amount":{
              "usd":0.99
           },
           "unit":"1GB of messages over 20GB"
        }
     ],
    "bullets": [
        "Shared fake server",
        "5 TB storage",
        "40 concurrent connections"
    ],
  }
}, {
  "name": "fake-plan-2",
  "id": "0f4008b5-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-dace631cd648",
  "description": "Shared fake Server, 5tb persistent disk, 40 max concurrent connections. 100 async",
  "max_storage_tb": 5,
  "metadata": {
    "costs":[
        {
           "amount":{
              "usd":199.0
           },
           "unit":"MONTHLY"
        },
        {
           "amount":{
              "usd":0.99
           },
           "unit":"1GB of messages over 20GB"
        }
     ],
    "bullets": [
      "40 concurrent connections"
    ]
  }
}]
}]
}
```

I have successfully created this endpoint in our PCF application and ran the command:

```
cf create-service-broker p-service myemail@whatever.com somethingSecure http://broker.url.com --space-scoped
Creating service broker p-service in org ourOrg / space dev as myemail@whatever.com...
OK
```

I can then see the service-broker in our Org. But when I click on the broker to view the 'plans' section I get the following errors in the console and the page does not direct.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at t.value (application.js:20)
    at p._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (react.js:13)
    at p._renderValidatedComponent (react.js:13)
    at performInitialMount (react.js:13)
    at p.mountComponent (react.js:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.js:15)
    at h.mountChildren (react.js:14)
    at h._createInitialChildren (react.js:13)
    at h.mountComponent (react.js:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.js:15)
react.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null
    at Object.getHostNode (react.js:15)
    at p.getHostNode (react.js:13)
    at Object.getHostNode (react.js:15)
    at Object.updateChildren (react.js:13)
    at h._reconcilerUpdateChildren (react.js:14)
    at h._updateChildren (react.js:14)
    at h.updateChildren (react.js:14)
    at h._updateDOMChildren (react.js:14)
    at h.updateComponent (react.js:13)
    at h.receiveComponent (react.js:13)
```

Is the only requirement for a working service broker the /v2/catalog api endpoint? Or do we need to implement the other endpoints from the documentation linked above? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a PCF version issue. Needed version 247 but had version 246.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same issue with PCF Dev 0.26.0 (CF 1.10.0). Would you mind explaining how exactly you solve this problem?. The version numbers 246, 247 are not very clear.

Comment: I was able workaround this problem using the CLI. It might be an issue in the PCF UI.

Comment: My versioning is probably incorrect - I was told by an admin that we were on "two forty six". He could have been saying 2.46.